# I cannot switch between subtabs

Tags: support, firefox

I cannot switch between certain subtabs.

**Update** The problem is more general. Below are where the tabs do not switch in Stackoverflow.

- `stats`: switching between `recent, views, newest, and votes`
- `stats`: switching between pages
- `reputation`: switching between `by post, by time, graph`
- `activity`: switching between `reviews, revisions, comments, badges, posts, accepts, all`
- `responses`: switching between `answers, comments, revisions, all`

Somehow, the following work:

- top page: switching between `Questions, Tags, Users, Badges, Unanswered`
- top page: switching between `interesting, featured, hot, week, month`
- question page: switching between `features, faq, votes, active, unanswered`
- `favorites`: switching between `added, recent, views, newest, votes`
- user page: switching between `info, reputation, activity, responses, favorites`
- user page: switching between `stats, prefs, accounts`

Comment: what web browser and OS? Did you clear your browser cache?

Comment: I am using Firefox 3.0.5 on Windows Vista SP2. Even after clearing the cache, the problem remains.

Comment: What happens when you try to click on one of them?

Comment: The button part scrolls to the top of the page (This is for the buttons that come in the middle of the page). The previously grayed button stays gray, and the clicked button does not become gray. The content does not change. The status bar at the bottom says 'Done'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using a version of Firefox that is almost 3 years old? Firefox 3.0 was released June 17, 2008.

We generally support the current release of a browser, the previous release, and the one before that.

For Firefox this would be

- 4.0
- 3.6
- 3.5

Is there any reason you can't upgrade to a version of Firefox newer than 3 years ago?

Comment: I am using a public computer. The maintenance is bad. If it is outside of support, I can also access stackoverflow at home. I will ask the moderator of the computer to upgrade the browser. I was not sure if the browser was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The pages you are having trouble with involve ajax javascript calls, it is likely javascript is not properly working on the browser, or the old browser no longer compatible.

As Jeff says, probably time to get an upgrade, I doubt we will fix any bugs on the site in 3 year old browsers.

Comment: Thank you. I asked the person in charge of the computer to upgrade Firefox.